# JOOQ API getPrimaryKey() returns null to each table?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have noticed that in JOOQ API the "tableByName("table_name").getPrimaryKey()" returns null. I guess this is because there is no real query happens in the background. Is it possible to force JOOQ API to check the table and read the meta data? Or this can be done only through querying the org.jooq.util.Database instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Table` object constructed with [`DSL.tableByName()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#tableByName%28java.lang.String...%29) is not connected to a database, so it couldn't dynamically fetch primary key information even if this was supported.

You can, however, get primary key information through [`DSLContext.meta()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta%28%29)[`.getPrimaryKeys()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Meta.html#getPrimaryKeys%28%29)

Comment: Are there any more selective way to list primary keys of a specific schema/table?
`for (Schema sch : create.meta().getSchemas()) {
 if ("chembl_17".equals(sch.getName())) {
 Table<?> tab = sch.getTable("protein_classification");
 if (tab != null) { UniqueKey<?> key = tab.getPrimaryKey();
 for (TableField<?, ?> f : key.getFields()) {
 System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", f.getName(), f.getDataType().getTypeName()); } } else { // no PK defined } } }` Sorry for the formating...

Comment: About the formatting, you can ask another question on Stack Overflow :-) (because the answer might be equally ill-formatted...)